# Resize fixed modal

Tags: html, css, resize

I have the following fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7q8nejo3/1/

I'm going to explain what I have know, and what I intent to achieve.

**NOW**

I have a fixed position modal in the middle of the page in a min-width and min-height ... that is for mobiles devices... all works ok... if you resize the page it's all fine.

**What I need**

Due to the min-width and min-height, the modal keeps its size, so I need that when the screen is bigger, the tourImage also increase its size. I try to use

```
width: 80%; min-width:260px;
```

This in order to resize the picture but didn't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this way. What you will get is that the width of the image won't overflow the container div.

@media screen and (max-width:800px){

```
.tourImage{
      position: relative;
      width: 80%;
      min-width: 260px;
      min-height: 340px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #55acee;
    }
    .popover{
      background:#fff;
      width: 80%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      position: fixed;;
      top: 50% !important;
      left: 50% !important;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
   }


 @media screen and (max-width:400px){
      .popover{
        width: auto;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yop,

I think  you need to add a width on your fixed modal, and on your image, like this :

```
.tourImage{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 260px;
  min-height: 340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  background: #55acee;
}
.popover{
  background:#fff;
  width: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7q8nejo3/4/

You can adjust the widths as you need.